# asp.net web page pass parameter to another page include "#"

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters

I use vs2010. c#
I need pass parameter from one page to another, it seems it's easy.
however I have a issue ,the new page cannot get the parameter value.
because of **"#"**

here is the sample

**this is page 1**

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<a href="WebForm2.aspx?item='#004'">go to webForm2</a>
</div>
</form>
```

**the page2**

```
 public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string item = Request.QueryString["item"];
        //here item value is empty.
    }
}
```

How to pass parameter with special character?

I find the encodeURIComponent can sovle the problem, but it seems don't need to decode in c# code.
here is the sample

**Page1:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function goto() {
        var id = '#004@$%^&?';
        var url = 'WebForm2.aspx?item=' + encodeURIComponent(id);
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

**Page2**

```
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string item = Request.QueryString["item"];
        Label1.Text = "pass value:" + item;
        //below the result is the same as above
        string value = Server.UrlDecode(item);
        Label2.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Here no need to decode.

Is that corrent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to encode the parameters which you are passing. You can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);` method for encoding parameters.

You can execute the c# code on .aspx page as follows

```
<a href="WebForm2.aspx?item=<%=HttpUtility.UrlEncode('#004')%>">go to webForm2</a>
```

Comment: I use javascript not c# to pass

Comment: You can execute the c# code on .aspx page. I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: I find the encodeURIComponent can solve the problem.